# How to detect when split polygon could have been multipolygon

Tags: python, shapely

When I split a polygon such that there are two disconnected pieces, I get a MultiPolygon. But when they tangent on a line, it gives me a polygon, like this example.

'POLYGON ((0 0.5, 0 0.95, 2 1.95, 2 1.1, 1.5 1.1, 1.5 1.5, 1.1 1.5, 1.1 1.1, 1 1.1, 1 1.2, 0.5 1.2, 0.5 0.5, 0 0.5))'

I was thinking it would be easy to detect these since they would have points of intersection. naively I was hoping to look at the exterior coords for duplicates. But, it can intersect at the line between two points, such as the example polygon (which was one of two geometries produced splitting it with `shapely.ops.split(poly, line)` with the diagonal line):

[image: sample problem shape]

To my mind, this should have produced a multipolygon. In fact, I believe I should convert it into a collection of regular polygons in such cases, so in addition to detecting these shapes, it would be awesome if you also had a dynamic way of splitting it into a multipolygon (or list of polygons). I am hoping the detection can be faster than looking at intersections between points and linestrings composed of each pair of points, as that would be pretty slow:

```py
def remove_self_tangents(S: Polygon) -> Polygon:
    """sketch approach to remove self tangents"""
    for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(S.exterior.coords, S.exterior.coords[1:])):
        for c in S.exterior.coords:
            if c == a or c == b:
                continue
            if c.touches(LineString([a, b])):
                S = Polygon(S.exterior.coords[:-1].insert(i+1,c)).simplify(TOLERANCE) # don't actually expect simplify will do it but, ...
    return S
```

edit:

I have my process now such that the above sample is never generated, but very near misses are still generated, such as:
'POLYGON ((0.5 0.5, 1 0.5, 1 1.110223024625157e-16, 0 0.9999999999999998, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1.2, 0.5 1.2, 0.5 0.5))'

[image: near-miss example]

The naive algorithm for fixing this is to round to some precision.. but again `.simplify`does not work here, I have to manually do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I went with

```py
# TOLERANCE = 1e-14 or something
def polygon_has_no_self_tangents(S: Polygon) -> Polygon:
    for a,b in zip(S.exterior.coords, S.exterior.coords[1:]):
        for c in S.exterior.coords:
            if c == a or c == b:
                continue
            np = nearest_points(LineString([a, b]), Point(c))
            if np[0].distance(np[1]) < TOLERANCE:
                return False
    return True
```